# `JSON.parse(await response.json())` throws SyntaxError: unexpected character at line 1 column 2

Tags: javascript, json, async-await, fetch

I want to bring back the `age` property from the JSON created by the API but it throws this error:

> `SyntaxError`: `JSON.parse`: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

The `console.log(await response.json())` gives me all my JSON data, but when I comment it out and put the last code line, this error occurs.

I was told to try one of these:

- `response.json()["age"]`
- `response.json()[age]`
- `response.json().age`
- `let json = JSON.parse(response);`

`console.log(json["age"])` was close, but not successful.

```js
let table = base.getTable("test");
let view = table.getView("Donnée brut");
let age;
let query = await view.selectRecordsAsync({
  sorts: [
    // sort by "Prénom" in ascending order...
    {
      field: "Prénom"
    }
  ]
});

// print ID & "Prénom" from each record:
for (let record of query.records) {
  let name = (record.getCellValueAsString('Prénom'));
  var response = await fetch('https://api.agify.io/?name=' + name);

  /* console.log(await response.json()); */

  let json = JSON.parse(await response.json());
  
  console.log(json["age"]);
}
```

Comment: What do you think the difference is between `response.json()` and `response.text()`?

Comment: "*I was told to try one of these*" - by whom? None of these work. What you need is `(await response.json())["age"]` or `(await response.json()).age` or `const data = await response.json(); console.log(data.age)`

Answer (score 3):

[`Response.prototype.json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) already parses the JSON.
You’re correctly awaiting this promise: `await response.json()`.
When logging, this already logs the parsed data you need: `console.log(await response.json());`.

When you try `JSON.parse(await response.json())`, you’re coercing the object back into a string, which results in `"[object Object]"`, which is invalid JSON, hence the error message.
Remove this `JSON.parse` call.

If you need the `age` property of the parsed JSON, use `console.log((await response.json()).age);`.
Remember that `.json` returns a Promise, not the parsed object; that’s why `response.json().age` and the like won’t work.
You need to await *before* reading the property.

Alternatively, put the parsed result in a variable first:

```js
// …

const result = await response.json();

console.log(result.age);

// …
```